# jqgrid and jqPivot: How to remove grouping when xDimension have multi value?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grouping, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I'm using free-jqgrid with jqPivot.

I want to change display of xDimension in pivot grid.

In document:

> These values are the cells from source data that appear as rows in the
>   grid. When more that one object element is set a grouping appear
>   automatically.

and I want to make it not grouping.

[image]

Any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last parameter of `jqPivot` is the object, where you can include almost any jqGrid option. You can add `grouping: false` option in the last parameter to switch the grouping off.

If you use `xDimension` with more as one element and you want to the number of grouping you can add `skipGrouping: true` property in the last elements of `xDimension`. The grouping of at least one (first) column will be hold in the way.